# Infraestructura de servidor para app movil

Tags: servidor, app, cloud

Hola estoy por terminar una aplicación en si pues se subirán fotos,estados,videos,chats,quisiera saber que tipo de servidores necesitaría para poder dar abasto  a los usuarios empecemos con 100,000 usuarios inicialmente, que tipo de servidores. necesitara para soportar las peticiones?

Comment: Es muy complicado adivinar una cosa así, se requieren muchas pruebas para determinar la reserva de ancho de banda por usuario, cpu, ram, etc... en base a los límites del proyecto si es que los hay. Por otro lado, existen servicios como los de amazon que te dejan tanta potencia como necesites.

Comment: y por ejemplo que provedores cres que sean mejores. por ejemplo IBM bluemix , Amazon,google cloud .

Comment: En qué tecnología está diseñado tu backend?

Comment: esta echa en nodejs y mysql y otra base de datos en mongodb

Comment: No puedo decirte que haría yo si no conozco el caso (a fondo), pero por norma general no creo en nada hasta tener la información requerida (o bien buscando en los proveedores o usando un buscador para encontrar casos similares) y menos creo si el sistema va a estar en producción sin pruebas ni nada.

Comment: Ah, por cierto, otra cosa a tener en cuenta es si son peticiones simultáneas o no, ya que no es lo mismo y el consumo difiere mucho de una a la otra.